# Javascript loop through array of strings and ints

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

Having this array:

```
const xx = [
  {
    name: "Alex",
    income: 324300,
    total: 3030000
  },
  {
    name: "Snake",
    income: 3433000,
    total: 34323000
  },
  {
    name: "Wake",
    income: 4,
    total: 3
  }
];
```

I want to loop through it and do something if the value is an int (income and total). How do i go about doing it?

This is what i have tried so far, i dont really know how to take out the objects value and test if it is an int

```
for (var key in xx) {
       var arr = xx[key];
       for( var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ ) {
           var obj = arr[ i ];
       }
    }
        }
```

Comment: `xx.forEach( (o) => { if (parseInt(o.income,10) == income && ...`

Answer (score 0):

try:

```js
const xx = [
  {
    name: "Alex",
    income: 324300,
    total: 3030000
  },
  {
    name: "Snake",
    income: 3433000,
    total: 34323000
  },
  {
    name: "Wake",
    income: 4,
    total: 3
  }
];

xx.forEach(item => {
  Object.keys(item).forEach(key => {
    if (!isNaN(parseInt(item[key])) && isFinite(item[key])) {
      // do something here
      console.log('INT: ' + item[key]);
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to exchange internal for with the external. and use:

- `typeof xx[i][k] === "number"` OR `xx[i][k] === +xx[i][k]` to check if value is
  a number.
- `parseInt(xx[i][k]) === xx[i][k]` to check if value is an **integer**
  number.

See example:

```js
const xx = [{
  name: "Alex",
  income: 324300,
  total: 3030000
}, {
  name: "Snake",
  income: 34.33000,
  total: 34323000
}, {
  name: "Wake",
  income: 4,
  total: 3
}];
for (var i = 0; i < xx.length; i++) {
  for (var k in xx[i]) {
    //if(parseInt(xx[i][k]) === xx[i][k]) //integer
    //if(typeof xx[i][k] == "number") //number
    if (xx[i][k] === +xx[i][k]) { //number
      console.log(k + ": " + xx[i][k]);
    }
  }
}
```